# Phaser: Stretch background image to 100%?

Tags: javascript, scale, phaser-framework

The easiest way to get a fullscreen background I guess is to set the dimension of the sprite as the games dimension.

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.CANVAS, '');
```

1. How would I give the sprite these pixel sizes?

2.If I create the game object with the string "100" in both width and height it will be as big as the screen, so what do I set the sprite to then?

Answer (score 0):

optionally, you can also use these methods to get the width and height in a pixel value

```
var w = window.innerWidth;
var h = window.innerHeight;
```

Comment: my problem was that I wasn't able to set the exact pixel size of the sprite. I did however find out that it was as simple as sprite.height / width.